# Не работает windows.location

Tags: jquery

Есть форма.

```
<form method="post" action="/admin/edit_category/<?echo $category['id']?>">
    <article class="module width_full">
            <header><h3>Новая категория</h3></header>
                <div class="module_content">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label>Наименование подкатегории</label>
                            <input type="text" value="<?echo $category['title']?>" name="title" required="">
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label>Наименование категории</label>
                            <input type="text" value="<?echo $main_category['title']?>" disabled="">
                        </fieldset>

                        <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            <footer>
                <div class="submit_link">
                    <input type="submit" value="Опубликовать" class="alt_btn" name="edit">
                    <input type="submit" value="Назад" class="back">
                </div>
            </footer>
        </article><!-- end of post new article -->
</form>
```

Есть скрипт

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".back").click(function(){
            window.location="/admin/list_categories";
             });
     });
</script>
```

При нажатии на кнопку назад, он не переходит по нужно ссылке в скрипте. Почему?

Comment: Потому что ошибку выбивает в консоли, которую вы не показываете нам)) А на основе нее можно было бы что-то сказать....может версия jquery не совместима с `click`

Comment: Консоль пустая, он на клик срабатывает, но тупо перезагружает страницу, а не переходит на ту которую мне нужно

Comment: Поменяйте `type="submit"` у кнопки Назад на `type="button"`, семантически не очень хорошо держать больше двух кнопок-сабмитов в одной форме.

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Comment: В принципе, как раз, проблема в этом и есть. Что срабатывает `submit` вместо клика. Непонятно зачем две кнопки сабмит